# My unsolved problem in jquery animation

Tags: jquery

I have written very simple image rotaror with jquery:

HTML:

```
<div class="left" id="main">
  <ul class="gmain" >
    <li class="active">
      <div class="gleft"><img src="images/php.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="300"  class="g-img"/> <span class="g-span">1-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dapibus urna nulla, et eleifend purus. Fusce nisl odio, aliquet vitae tempor sit amet, </span></div>
      <div class="list"> <a href="#"><img src="images/php_thumb.jpg" alt="Image Name" height="45" width="45"/> <span class="title">Fusce nisl odio, aliquet</span> <span class="date">01.01.2010</span> </a> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="gleft"><img src="images/bat.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="300"  class="g-img"/> <span class="g-span">2-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dapibus urna nulla, et eleifend purus. Fusce nisl odio, aliquet vitae tempor sit amet, </span></div>
      <div class="list"> <a href="#"><img src="images/bat.jpg" alt="Image Name" height="45" width="45"/> <span class="title">Fusce nisl odio, aliquet</span> <span class="date">01.01.2010</span> </a> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="gleft"><img src="images/cat.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="300"  class="g-img"/> <span class="g-span">3-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dapibus urna nulla, et eleifend purus. Fusce nisl odio, aliquet vitae tempor sit amet, </span></div>
      <div class="list"> <a href="#"><img src="images/cat.jpg" alt="Image Name" height="45" width="45"/> <span class="title">Fusce nisl odio, aliquet</span> <span class="date">01.01.2010</span> </a> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="gleft"><img src="images/php.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="300"  class="g-img"/> <span class="g-span">4-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dapibus urna nulla, et eleifend purus. Fusce nisl odio, aliquet vitae tempor sit amet, </span></div>
      <div class="list"> <a href="#"><img src="images/php_thumb.jpg" alt="Image Name" height="45" width="45"/> <span class="title">Fusce nisl odio, aliquet</span> <span class="date">01.01.2010</span> </a> </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="gleft"><img src="images/bat.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="300"  class="g-img"/> <span class="g-span">5-Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dapibus urna nulla, et eleifend purus. Fusce nisl odio, aliquet vitae tempor sit amet, </span></div>
      <div class="list"> <a href="#"><img src="images/bat.jpg" alt="Image Name" height="45" width="45"/> <span class="title">Fusce nisl odio, aliquet</span> <span class="date">01.01.2010</span> </a> </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.gmain{

position:relative;
height:315px;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
}
.gleft{
float:left;
width:469px;

 }
 .g-img{
position:absolute;
top:8px;
left:8px;
visibility:hidden;
 }
 .active .g-img, .active .g-span{
visibility:visible;
 }
.g-span{
position:absolute;
bottom:8px;
left:8px;
width:430px;
padding:10px;
font:normal 11px/13px verdana;
display:block;
background:#333;
color:#FFF;
visibility:hidden;
}
```

and my jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

$(".gmain .g-span").animate({ opacity: 0.60 }, 1 ); 

$("#main ul li").mouseover(function(){
    $("#main ul li").removeClass("active");
    var fade = $('> img', this);
    fade.fadeIn(250);

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

});

All thing works but i want to fade left side img.

```
var fade = $('> img', this);
    fade.fadeIn(250);
```

This line not working? What is wrong in my js code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try: $(this).prev().find('img').fadeIn(250)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var fade = $('img:first', this);
```

This will select the first image. Or did you want to select the image's container and fade that?

To select by class name:

```
 var fade = $('img.g-img', this);
```

EDIT:

jasmine, this should work. It will select all images with class '.g-img' that are within the element that received the 'mouseover' event.

Maybe there's something else going on.

Your function should look like this:

```
$("#main ul li").mouseover(function(){
    $("#main ul li").removeClass("active");
    var fade = $('img.g-img', this);
    fade.fadeIn(250);

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Hi jasmine. My solution will always select the first. You could always select it by class name as well. I'll add that solution.

Comment: var fade = $('.g-img', this); not working already. image vanishes :(

Comment: @jasmine - If the image is vanishing, there is something else wrong. Be aware that the solution you accepted will select **all** images. The first part: `$('#' +$(this).attr('id') + ' img')` is the same as doing `$('img',this)`, but there is no definition given to which `img` is being selected.

Comment: ( *Meant to say "the solution you accepted will select all images within the element receiving the mouseover event* ")

Comment: now its ok patrick:
 $(document).ready(function() {
       
  $("#main ul li").mouseover(function(){
    $("#main ul li").removeClass("active");
    var fade = $('img.g-img', this);
    fade.fadeTo('slow', 0.5);

    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});

 
}); 

I will working to remove event when mouse out.
Thank you patrick

Answer (score 0):

how about changing fade to :

```
var fade = $('#' +$(this).attr('id') + ' > img');
```

or

```
var fade = $('#' +$(this).attr('id') + ' img');
```

Comment: with this: var fade = $('#' +$(this).attr('id') + ' > img'); if (fade.is(':animated')) { fade.stop().fadeTo(250, 1); } else { fade.fadeIn(250); } }, function () { var fade = $('#' +$(this).attr('id') + ' > img'); if (fade.is(':animated')) { fade.stop().fadeTo(3000, 0); } else { fade.fadeOut(3000); } image vanishe